# Pass state to parent from material ui selectable list

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a selectable list with the exact code that is on their website which is:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import MobileTearSheet from '../../../MobileTearSheet';
import {List, ListItem, makeSelectable} from 'material-ui/List';
import Avatar from 'material-ui/Avatar';
import Subheader from 'material-ui/Subheader';

let SelectableList = makeSelectable(List);

function wrapState(ComposedComponent) {
  return class SelectableList extends Component {
static propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  defaultValue: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};

componentWillMount() {
  this.setState({
    selectedIndex: this.props.defaultValue,
  });
}

handleRequestChange = (event, index) => {
  this.setState({
    selectedIndex: index,
  });
};

render() {
  return (
    <ComposedComponent
      value={this.state.selectedIndex}
      onChange={this.handleRequestChange}
    >
      {this.props.children}
    </ComposedComponent>
  );
    }
  };
}

SelectableList = wrapState(SelectableList);

const ListExampleSelectable = () => (
  <MobileTearSheet>
<SelectableList defaultValue={3}>
  <Subheader>Selectable Contacts</Subheader>
  <ListItem
    value={1}
    primaryText="Brendan Lim"
    leftAvatar={<Avatar src="images/ok-128.jpg" />}
    nestedItems={[
      <ListItem
        value={2}
        primaryText="Grace Ng"
        leftAvatar={<Avatar src="images/uxceo-128.jpg" />}
      />,
    ]}
  />
  <ListItem
    value={3}
    primaryText="Kerem Suer"
    leftAvatar={<Avatar src="images/kerem-128.jpg" />}
  />
  <ListItem
    value={4}
    primaryText="Eric Hoffman"
    leftAvatar={<Avatar src="images/kolage-128.jpg" />}
  />
  <ListItem
    value={5}
    primaryText="Raquel Parrado"
    leftAvatar={<Avatar src="images/raquelromanp-128.jpg" />}
  />
</SelectableList>
  </MobileTearSheet>
    );

export default ListExampleSelectable;
```

I want to be able to get the value of the updated selectedIndex inside another function but I try to do

```
export default class Parent extends React.Component {
      componentWillMount() {
      this.setState({
        selectedIndex: this.props.defaultValue,
      });
    }

    handleRequestChange = (event, index) => {
      this.setState({
        selectedIndex: index,
      });
    };

render(){
  <SelectableList index={this.state.selectedIndex} change=
{this.handleRequestChange} />
}

}
```

and after that I change the render function of the SelectableList class with

```
<ComposedComponent
      value={this.props.index}
      onChange={this.props.change}
    >
      {this.props.children}
    </ComposedComponent>
```

Comment: Is there an error?  What is your question?

Comment: When I have it as the first code it works but when I get the handleRequestchange function and put it in the parent and pass it to the child as a prop it stops working